# Ajax запрос php, Mysql с русскими словами не работает( все кодировки в порядке)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Извините за такой глупый вопрос, я просмотрел очень много статей и ссылок с данной проблемой , но ни одна мне не помогла. В чем суть проблемы, я делаю поиск для своего сайта , через Ajax. С англ символами все работает, а с русскими нет. Вот сам Ajax запрос

```
    $('.who').bind("change keyup input click", function() {
    
            if (this.value.length >= 2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'scripts/search.php',
                    data: 'referal=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: _onAjaxError,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.code === 'success') {
                            console.log(response)
                        } else {
                            _onAjaxError(response);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

подключение к бд

```
define('DB_HOST', '');
 define('DB_USER', '');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
 define('DB_NAME', '');
 
 
 function connectDB() {
     $errorMessage = 'Невозможно подключиться к серверу базы данных';
     $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
     if (!$conn)
         throw new Exception($errorMessage);
     else {
         $query = $conn->query('set names utf8');
         if (!$query)
             throw new Exception($errorMessage);
         else
             return $conn;
     }
 }
```

Сама база данных все таблицы и столбцы в utf-8. Вот код в php, в php принимаю данные urldecode($_GET['referal']);

```
function getGoods($options, $conn) {
    $referal = $options['referal'];
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM `goods` WHERE `good` like '%$referal%'
    ";
    $data = $conn->query($query);
    return $data->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Если например сделать $referal = 'мыло', то запрос работает отлично, но если я в браузере руками вбиваю "мыло", то приходит пустой массив.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nCXu.png

Comment: *Если например сделать $referal = 'мыло', то запрос работает отлично, но если я в браузере руками вбиваю "мыло", то приходит пустой массив.* Это говорит о том, что кодировка портится по пути из браузера в PHP.

Comment: Сразу с гугла тонна ответов и решений.  Проблема в кодировке. Как вариант - http://tradebenefit.ru/problemy-s-kodirovkoj-dannyh-v-jquery-ajax-i-php

Comment: @Akina Я тоже думал об этом. И поэтому пробовал сделать вот так $referal = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $_GET['referal']);

Comment: @sousage1212 То, что вы скинули все в моем коде есть начиная с Ajax и заканчиваю подключением к бд.

Comment: @Only091 Выведите $_GET['referal']. Что показывает ? Заголовок кодировки на странице есть ? Content-type

Comment: Ну так повводите немного в браузере, а в PHP сливайте полученное из браузера в гексах - сможете понять, какую кодировку принимает браузер и во что она преобразуется. А потом на стороне PHP сделайте обратное преобразование в кодировку, которую надо передавать в запрос.

Comment: @sousage1212 Заголовок кодировки есть,  $_GET['referal'] выводит в консоль, то что я ввожу, даже русские символы выводит корректно. Там в конце моего вопроса, скриншот на нём , text = 'мыло'  - это и есть $_GET

Comment: @Akina Извините, я новичок в этом деле, не особо понял что значит посливать полученно из браузера в гексах.

Comment: В PHP есть функция ( кажется, bin2hex), которая конвертирует строку в шестнадцатиричные коды её символов. Посливать - куда-то вывести (в консоль отладки или файл).

Comment: @Akina Понял, а как я пойму в какой кодировке приходит запрос?

Comment: После конвертации "мыло" получается вот это - "d0bcd18bd0bbd0be"

Comment: @Only091 mb_detect_encoding  попробуйте, гляньте, в какой кодировке символы

Comment: @sousage1212 Если пишу русские символы то - UTF-8. Если пишу на англ то - ASCII

Comment: Проблему решил. Дело было в самописной функции- обработчики информации массива _GET, он и портил русские слова. Спасибо всем кто ответил